# Android searchview remove hint padding

Tags: java, android, searchview

I'm working in my app and have a searchview inside toolbar but the hint has a small padding after the cursor.

How can I remove the padding?

Here is my searchview:

[image: searchview]

and I would like that:

[image: searchview with no padding]

here is my onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
SearchManager searchManager=(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.procura);
    Drawable drawable = menu.findItem(R.id.procura).getIcon();
    if (drawable != null) {
        drawable.mutate();
        drawable.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }

    searchView=(SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.app_hint));

    try {
        Field mDrawable = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mSearchHintIcon");
        mDrawable.setAccessible(true);
        Drawable drw = (Drawable) mDrawable.get(searchView);
        drw.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My styles:

```
<style name="SearchViewMy" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <item name="submitBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

My menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/procura"
    android:title="@string/app_hint"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Comment: Please post any relevant code, it helps people if we can replicate your issue as then we can try to solve it!

Comment: without the code we won't be able to help you

Comment: I added java code and my styles if you need more ask me

Comment: Can you mention why you use reflection and don't follow the examples from the docs? I don't understand the customization you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I try to folowing the docs because of that i ask this question in docs searchview dont have this padding after the cursor my idea is to remove that and at this point i removed the underline of query textview and remove hint icon, to follow the docs only need to remove that padding, like the second image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

Just add this in the styles:

```
<item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
```

The styles now is that:

```
<style name="SearchViewMy" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <item name="submitBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And onCreateOptionsMenu now is that:

```
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);


    SearchManager searchManager=(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.procura);

    searchView=(SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.app_hint));


    return true;
```